# Where can I buy icons for my app?

Tags: iphone

I know a few websites sell iPhone icon sets but I am looking for a website that I can buy one or two icons from the sets. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Most of the sets are not that expensive plus you'd get to use them on other projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://glyphish.com/ - free and paid icons.  I think it's all-or-nothing for the paid set.

Comment: These are really nice, and super affordable! They also cover a wide range of domains.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.istockphoto.com/ has lots of icon sets.

Answer (score 0):

This one has quite a few different icon templates and is really cheap.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/shameless-advertising/69675-ios-icon-template-pack.html